# IP from a different subnet is registered even after node and resource were removed

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability, dns

We run two SQL server at primary site in AlwaysOn High Availability Group on subnet 10.10.0.0/24
A third SQL server is running on secondary site in a different subnet 10.10.1.0/24
We have had third server as part of a cluster for some time [until faced issue from this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89167/multiple-ips-registered-for-listener-when-using-alwayson-ags-w-multi-subnet-clu). It was then decided to remove the third server from the cluster and all of the resources that it presented.

Right off the bat DNS registration for 10.10.1.0/24 subnet had to be removed, but it is now being registered every 24 hours. Whenever it is registered, all clients start to use and fail to connect. This occurred even when all three servers were running and syncing properly, and some clients would just drop live connection just to connect to ip on a different subnet which would fail.

Where can I find this 10.10.1.0/24 subet IP address that is still being registered with DNS server? SQL Management studio group listener lists only one IP in correct subnet. Fail-over cluster lists single network IP address too. The third server has since been powered off, but it is irrelevant

```
Get-ClusterGroup SQLHA | Get-ClusterResource | Where-Object {$_
.ResourceType -match "Network Name*"} | Update-ClusterNetworkNameResource -Verbose
```

After running this command DNS server is updated, but yet again two records are created.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alwaysonpro/archive/2014/06/03/connection-timeouts-in-multi-subnet-availability-group.aspx

Comment: I have seen that post and thought about applying those changes to avoid having multiple dns records to different IPs, but the whole idea of having third server at different site has been scraped  and third server was removed from availability group and cluster. None of its resources show up in cluster manager, yet somehow every 24 hours a second DNS record for availability group is registered with DNS server. What role is responsible for making this registration?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/07/17/9836756.aspx  If the network name group is not moved or there are no new dependencies or there are no changes to the name, then the registration is refreshed only once in 24 hours.  Have you tried flushing DNS? The purpose of the RegisterAllProvidersIP parameter is to make sure the DNS entry is already written to the DNS server on the other network subnet. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6f9f82e-6494-47ee-af2e-e388665a00a7/how-to-force-a-dns-record-update-for-an-availability-group-listener?forum=sqldisasterrecovery